# How to store and sometimes update a global variable in Silex

Tags: php, silex

I need to do what seems to be a simple thing be can't get it work: I just need a variable (currently an array of dates) to be stored somewhere when a page load, and sometime access and modify thoses dates in other actions of my controller.

I've already tried:

Setting this variable as a member of my custom `User` class, but I am only able to set it at the creation of the class, I can't update it with new values in other actions, because when i try `$app['user']->setDates($dates)` and later do `$app['user']->getDates()`, I get the old, not updated, values.

I also tried to set up a shared service like this:

```
$app['utils'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new \MyProject\Utils\Utils($app);
});
```

which is a simple class with one private member and its associated getter/setter, but still the same issue : when a try to get what I expect to be an updated value, I get the old one.

I'm sure my problem is in my understanding of how Pimple/Silex actually work, could you please explain to me how can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Why won't you store them into a database and update them there if you need to?

Comment: @KhorneHoly, those dates already come from a stored procedure, I don't want to call this procedure every time I need those values, I just want theme update in one particular action, and use the updated version in other actions without making a DB call. Please tell me if I'm not really clear.

Comment: You could write them in a temp file or something, but if you change the dates, do you want that the changes get lost after some time?

Comment: @KhorneHoly Yes of course writing into a file would do the job, but I was looking for a more "code-only" way to do it. Ideally, I would like to be able to put this array of dates into my custom User class and use getter/setter to get and update this array across all of my controllers' actions, but it seems like the Instance of $app['user'] that I use in the actions is not the same as the one on which I do the "set", that is why I lose my update...

Comment: why can't you store it like a parameter in the container (remember, the $app instance *is* the container) like so ```$app['myvar'] = 'my value'```?